# How can i send keys to an iframe when iframe is the only element in the iframe

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, iframe, headless

I have this iframe which is for inputting the card number.

I am trying this in chrome headless mode

```
<iframe hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 

html inside the iframe with #document
#document
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><style>*{margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border:none;background-color:transparent}body,form,input{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%}label{position:absolute;left:-9999px}:focus{outline:0}::-ms-clear,input::-ms-clear{display:none}.autocomplete,.field-description,.focus-helper{opacity:0;pointer-events:none;width:1px;height:1px;left:-1px;z-index:-1}.autocomplete{width:2px;height:2px;left:-2px}</style><style></style></head><body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"><script src="iframe.min.js"></script><form><input class="focus-helper start" tabindex="0" readonly="" aria-hidden="true" autocomplete="off" autocompletetype="off" x-autocompletetype="off"><input name="number" type="tel" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="Card number" maxlength="22" autocomplete="cc-number" autocompletetype="cc-number" x-autocompletetype="cc-number" placeholder=" " aria-placeholder=" " class="invalid"><input type="text" name="name" id="name-autocomplete" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="cc-name" autocompletetype="cc-name" x-autocompletetype="cc-name" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="expirationMonth" id="expirationMonth-autocomplete" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="cc-exp-month" autocompletetype="cc-exp-month" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp-month" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="expirationYear" id="expirationYear-autocomplete" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="cc-exp-year" autocompletetype="cc-exp-year" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp-year" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><input class="focus-helper end" tabindex="0" readonly="" aria-hidden="true" autocomplete="off" autocompletetype="off" x-autocompletetype="off"></form></body></html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) : The code that you have written perhaps, and the website link if it is ok to share

Answer (score 0):

Write the `Xpath` for that `iframe` like the below. As you mentioned

> I have this iframe which is for inputting the card number.

so there is an attribute for for card number.

```
//iframe[@attribute='value']
```

Eg:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@attribute='value']"));

ele.sendKeys('Text');
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@attribute='value']")));

WebElement inputtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@attribute='value']"));

inputtext.sendKeys("text");
```

Hope this answer your question, please share the HTML from inspect element if this does not answer your question.

Comment: You don't `sendKeys()` to `<iframe>` element but to within a WebElement.